# Laravel: login strange issue

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

i am observing very strange situation with my login form. The first version of my login was the simple login with email and password. It was working fine till i alter my users table to have another field "status". I want only confirmed by administrator users so be able to login. So i added the "status" field to the attempt()-method as follows:

```
if ($this->auth->attempt([$this->loginUsername() => $request->input($this->loginUsername()), 'password' => $request->input('password'), 'status' => 1], $request->has('remember')))
```

the first time when i try to log, the login was successful. Than i log out and try to login again, but i am not able to login. Reason: "These credentials do not match our records."

If i try again to login with 'unused' user than i can login again, but after log out this username is no more accessible. Why is that happening ?

Comment: What happens to the status column of a user when he logs in?

Comment: nothing. I think it is something with the remember_token, but if i manually remove the remember_token of user, it does not change anything.

Comment: i think i found the problem. Google chrome has stored wrong password for the user, thats why i cannot log in :)

Comment: Are you able to log in again when you remove the remember_token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was my bad. Chrome stores false password, that's why i cannot login